# Python Regex: Replace all urls in string with <img> and <a> tags

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a string with many urls to some pages and images:

`La-la-la https://example.com/ la-la-la https://example.com/example.PNG`

And I need to convert it to:

`La-la-la <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> la-la-la <img src="https://example.com/example.PNG">`

Image formats are unpredictable, they can be `.png` `.JPEG` etc., and any links can be found multiple times per string

*I understand, that there are some strange javascript examples here, but I can not get how to convert them to python.*

**But I found this as a starting point:**

`url_regex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig`
`img_regex = /^ftp|http|https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/ig`

*Big thx for help*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `regex`, if you want.

```
stng = 'La-la-la https://example.com/ la-la-la https://example.com/example.PNG'

sentance = '{f_txt} <a href="{f_url}">{f_url}</a> {s_txt} <img src="{s_url}">'

f_txt, f_url, s_txt, s_url = stng.split()

print(sentance.format(f_txt=f_txt, f_url=f_url, s_txt=s_txt, s_url=s_url))
```

**Output**

```
La-la-la <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> la-la-la <img src="https://example.com/example.PNG">
```

Comment: But the sequence of text and links is undefined and unpredictable

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regular expression:

`(https?.*?\.com\/)(\s+[\w-]*\s+)(https?.*?\.com\/[\w\.]+)`

- `(https?.*?\.com\/)` First capture group. Capture `http` or `https`, anything up to `.com` and forward slash `/`.
- `(\s+[\w-]*\s+)` Second capture group. Capture whitespace, alphanumerical characters and hypens, and whitespace. You can add more characters to the character set if needed.
- `(https?.*?\.com\/[\w\.]+)` Third capture group. Capture `http` or `https`, anything up to `.com`, forward slash `/`, alphanumerical characters and full stop `.` for the extension. Again you can add more characters to the character set in this capture group if you are expecting other characters.

You can test the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/cJDtcm/2).

Alternatively, if you are expecting variable urls and domains you may use:

`(\w*\:.*?\.\w*\/)(\s+[\w-]*\s+)(\w*\:?.*?\.\w*\/[\w\.]+)`

Where first and third capture groups now do match any alphanumerical characters followed by colon `:`, and anything up to a `.`, alphanumerical characters `\w` and forward slash. You can test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/cJDtcm/4).

You may replace captured groups with:

`<a href="\1">\1</a>\2<img src="\3">`

Where `\1`, `\2`, and `\3` are backreferences to captured groups one, two and three respectively.

---

Python snippet:

```
>>import re
>>str = "La-la-la https://example.com/ la-la-la https://example.com/example.PNG"

>>out = re.sub(r'(https?.*?\.com\/)(\s+[\w-]*\s+)(https?.*?\.com\/[\w\.]+)',
       r'<a href="\1">\1</a>\2<img src="\3">',
       str)
>>print(out)
La-la-la <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> la-la-la <img src="https://example.com/example.PNG">
```

Comment: The sequence of text and links is undefined and unpredictable, it can be not only .com, not only .httpS, etc :)

Comment: Right, try `(\w*\:.*?\.\w*\/)(\s+[\w-]*\s+)(\w*\:?.*?\.\w*\/[\w\.]+)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/cJDtcm/4). If this solution does not work for you, can you please provide examples which fail this last regex?